# Dropdown value patch based on cursor position in textarea

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I have a **textarea** and a **dropdown**. When I select a value in the **dropdown**
the particular value will appear or get inserted or added to the text area . So after typing dear if a user selects
a **dropdown** value called name it should appear as a dear name in the text area. I have done it but there is a bug

The **dropdown** value gets patched based on the maximum postion the cursor went instead
of the current cursor position. say for example you type three words and you place the cursor
near the first word and select a **dropdown** value the value gets patched on the en of third word(maximum position) instead
of the current cursor position
I want the dropdown value to be patched on current cursor position

HTML:

```
<textarea [(ngModel)]='textValue' rows="10" cols="70">
</textarea>
<div>
  <mat-form-field class="input-style">
    <mat-select (change)="changeValue($event)">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let li of list4" [value]="li">
        {{li}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

Ts:

```
changeValue(ev) {
this.textValue += ` ${ev.value}`; }
```

Kindly help if you guys know

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-form-field-rjr5tu?file=app%2Fform-field-prefix-suffix-example.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need take account the "selectionStart" and selectionEnd of the textArea. For this, create a template reference variable and pass to the function

```
<!--see the #text-->
<textarea #text [(ngModel)]='textValue' rows="10" cols="70">
</textarea>
...
    <!--pass the "variable" to the function changeValue-->
    <mat-select (change)="changeValue($event,text)">
      ...
    </mat-select>
```

Then your function changeValue

```
  changeValue(ev,textArea:any) {
    const posInitial=textArea.selectionStart;
    const posFinal=textArea.selectionEnd;
    this.textValue = this.textValue.substr(0,posInitial)+
                     ev.value+
                     this.textValue.substr(posFinal);
  }
```

NOTE: If you don't want pass the "text" to the function you can also use ViewChild

```
@ViewChild("text") textArea:ElementRef
```

And to get the positions using

```
const posInitial=this.textArea.nativeElement.selectionStart;
const posFinal=this.textArea.nativeElement.selectionEnd;
```

See that in this case you use this.textArea.ElementRef

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-form-field-maasnk?file=app%2Fform-field-prefix-suffix-example.ts)

Comment: You're so quick, see my updated answer with the stackblitz

Comment: your solution worked. For understanding purpose I gave you a sample function in that stackblitz. In real I have a complex function. When I try to implement this solution there I get double the values. Can you please update in that link?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-form-field-tfw6de?file=app%2Fform-field-prefix-suffix-example.html     @Eliseo